# Parse.com- Get posts of non loggedin user by username

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm trying to get Posts of non-loggedin user by its username.

I have field "parent" that is associated with user on each post.

I tried many versions but didn't show posts of specific user

How to fetch all posts by parents username?

```
$viewUser = $_GET['user'];

echo $viewUser;

$user = ParseUser::query();
$user->equalTo("username", $viewUser); 
//$results = $query->find();
$user =$user->find();
$query = new ParseQuery("UsersPost");
//$query->includeKey("parent");
var_dump($user);
$query->equalTo("parent", $user);
$results = $query->find();
```

**EDIT:**
With two calls to database i could change:
`$user =$user->find();`
should be
 
`$user =$user->first();`
and then it works

I still would like to make it in one database call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

```
$viewUser = $_GET['user'];
$user = new ParseQuery("_User");
$user->equalTo("username", $viewUser);
$query = new ParseQuery("UsersPost");
$query->matchesQuery("parent", $user); #'parent' is where user relation is stored
```